# Font Styles (Segoe UI Symbol)

Tags: fonts

I have a .docx file with the "Segoe UI Symbol" font style.

Now I have to make a .pdf file with latex and should use this font style again. How do I do that?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search for "Segoe UI Symbol" on this site.

Comment: I already tried but couldn find anything.

I tried this: 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}

but it didnt work

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a sensible problem description.

Comment: And "Search for "Segoe UI Symbol" on this site." not a real answer ^^

Comment: Sure, that's why I added my remark as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, keep learning :)

This compiles with XeLaTeX, it is much better when you are dealing with different fonts and encodings.

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}%to generate dummy data
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}

\title{A Lovely Segoe UI Symbol Title}
\author{Jon Doe}
\date{11-11-2011}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1-10] %generate dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It compiles with lualatex also.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to lualatex and tried it but I get the following error: ! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"!! Control sequence \latinencoding already defined.!! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \tl_new:N \latinencoding

Comment: I just reinstalled the fontspec package and the error is now gone. But it still is not using the font i want...

Comment: Please asd your minimum working example to check it

Comment: I added two pictures to the main question

Comment: This is not a MWE. Check this https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/91967

Comment: Nevermind I just figured out what went wrong. Somewhere in my document it changed my fontstyle to a default...